# How to find the platform of a running process

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, x86-64

I have a `x86_64` machine, and it can run `IA32` process because I have installed a 32bits library. Now I want to know what's the platform that a running process is using? 64bits or 32bits?

The only way I can access the process is a `ptrace` system call; I don't have executable file (like I can just execute the file but I don't have read and write permissions), so I can't get the ELF header.

The OS I'm using is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I don't want to get executable file, and then analyse the ELF format. The *ONLY WAY* I can access the process is `ptrace`, or other system calls same as `ptrace` if you know, please tell me. Because I want to analyse the process in a C program.

Comment: Does `ldd` work?  (It actually executes the file, with some hidden option)

Comment: @BenVoigt nop, actually it's a running process. I attach it by `ptrace`.

Comment: Do you have access to lsof?

Answer (score 1):

This was also asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106234/determine-if-a-specific-process-is-32-or-64-bit, with limited success / viability for detection methods other than checking ELF headers after getting to them in various ways.

Looking at `/proc/<pid>/maps` for 64-bit addresses looks viable.  So does checking the bitness of `/proc/<pid>/exe`:

```
$ file - < /proc/$(pidof a.out)/exe
/dev/stdin: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=ff6b5084918be4e4daf7e4315fa4d6dd6a039ae7, for GNU/Linux 4.4.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

(Or `file -L` to follow symlinks. If you just use `file /.../exe`, it tells you `symbolic link to /tmp/a.out`.)

Note that files in `/proc` track the actual inode, so replacing `/tmp/a.out` with a different executable does *not* throw this off.  Opening it for reading will open the actual executable that this process has mapped, separate from the name it would report via a `readlink()` system call.  If that inode has no directory entries anymore, file will report `symbolic link to /tmp/a.out (deleted)`, but opening for reading will still get the contents.  And renaming `a.out` will get the kernel to report the new name as the symlink, like `/tmp/bar`.

---

This answer previously suggested looking at `/proc/<pid>/personality`, but the difference I was seeing was that a 32-bit process had the `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC` bit set.  That's likely because I built a 32-bit executable from asm sources I had been playing with at the time, without the `.note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits` that overrides the default of executable stacks, previously implemented by making *all* pages executable: *[Unexpected exec permission from mmap when assembly files included in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260465/unexpected-exec-permission-from-mmap-when-assembly-files-included-in-the-project)*

A 32-bit executable compiled by `gcc -m32` has personality `00000000`, same as 64-bit `/bin/sleep`.  So this isn't a useful detection mechanism, unfortunately.  I was hoping that 32-bit processes would have some bits set like `ADDR_LIMIT_32BIT`, but apparently that's implicit for a 32-bit process, perhaps as part of the "execution domain" like `PER_LINUX32`.

I got `00400000` (just `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC`) for a 32-bit process with executable stacks (and everything else).  (And `00440000` when I had it stopped in a debugger.)  The `proc(5)` man page says it tells you the personality as set by [`personality(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html).

Kernel source for personality bit-numbers: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/personality.h

glibc's copy: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/personality.h;hb=HEAD

Mostly leaving this part of the answer here in case the part about decoding personalities is useful to future readers.  It's not relevant to finding the bitness of a running process.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [xocopy](http://reverse.lostrealm.com/tools/xocopy.html) to create a copy of the executable in question and dump the ELF header from the copy created.

This tool and the problem you are describing was discussed [elsewhere](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-can-i-analyse-an-executable-with-no-read-permission) and that discussion may be helpful to you as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The work I'm doing is partly same as `xocopy`. I don't want to get the executable file. I just want to analysis the platform the process is using with `ptrace` system call.

Comment: @litao3rd: The C source code for `xocopy` programmatically locates and then reads the ELF header using `ptrace` - that would seem to meet your needs of executing this analysis from a C program (GPL applies).

Comment: yep, I read the source of `xocopy`, it works by searching ELF header in the memory. But it isn't what I want. Thanks for your reply again. :P